# Automatic incremental backup of MySql on windows

Tags: mysql, backup

I have three Mysql Servers, **Server-1**, **Server-2 and Server-3** all running on Windows. I have to configure Master-Master replication on **Server-2** and **Server-3**.

But **Server-2 has to be a mirror of Server-1**. I have configured binlog on server-1. So I basically need a cron job that can run daily and ftp all the bin-logs created by Server-1 to the system having Server-2 and execute the queries from these binlogs on Server-2. Once the Server-2 gets into the same state as Server-1, I want all the bin logs to be deleted.

How should I do that.

Comment: why not set the replication and introduce the delay in replication of say 24 hours...SQL_Delay is the parameter that would be used. what's the challenge of not using that one?